# Scala - Replace text placeholders in a String

Tags: string, scala, parsing, replace

Lets say that I have a string template which contains N number of placeholders:

```
"{placeholder1}/{placeholder2}-{placeholder3}/{placeholder4}.{placeholder5}"
```

And let's say that I have a map:

```
"placeholder1" -> "aaa", 
"placeholder2" -> "xxx", 
"placeholder3" -> "yyy", 
"placeholder4" -> "zzz", 
"placeholder5" -> "bbb"
```

Given this map and placeholder string template, is it possible to replace the placeholder keys with the placeholder values? Or would this require using regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can iterate over the data and apply to the template using [`String.replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)), and keep iterating on new state.

Given,

```
scala> val template = "{placeholder1}/{placeholder2}-{placeholder3}/{placeholder4}.{placeholder5}"
template: String = {placeholder1}/{placeholder2}-{placeholder3}/{placeholder4}.{placeholder5}

scala> val data = Map("placeholder1" -> "aaa", 
                      "placeholder2" -> "xxx", 
                      "placeholder3" -> "yyy", 
                      "placeholder4" -> "zzz", 
                      "placeholder5" -> "bbb")
data: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = HashMap(placeholder5 -> bbb, placeholder1 -> aaa, placeholder3 -> yyy, placeholder2 -> xxx, placeholder4 -> zzz)
```

apply the template on data using `foldLeft`. I'm assuming `{}` indicates the template placeholder.

```
scala> data.foldLeft(template){ case (newState, kv) => newState.replace(s"{${kv._1}}", kv._2)}
res6: String = aaa/xxx-yyy/zzz.bbb
```

**NOTE:** `kv` above is each entry in `Map`, alternatively, you can deconstruct `kv` as `(k, v)`.

```
scala> data.foldLeft(template){ case (newState, (k, v)) => newState.replace(s"{$k}", v)}
res7: String = aaa/xxx-yyy/zzz.bbb
```

**[Alternative solution](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/prayagupd/x5XP32ZdTeuNoqSR86hxig):**

Though `.foldLeft` is enough, you can write your own vanilla recursive that applies one entry at a time and keeps iterating until data is empty.

```
def format(template: String, data: Map[String, String]): String = {
  if(data.isEmpty) template
  else format(template.replace(s"{${data.head._1}}", data.head._2), data.tail)
}

val formatted = format(template, data) // aaa/xxx-yyy/zzz.bbb
```

Comment: Nice, but if you `case (newState,(k,v))` then you can simply `replace(s"{$k}", v)`.

Answer (score 0):

why not use [string interpolation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html)

```
def replace(m: Map[String,String]) = s"${m("placeholder1")}/${m("placeholder2")}-...."
```

Comment: Since the string template may be dynamic, is it possible to have this method take the the string template and also use interpolation?

Comment: not that I know of - but if the placeholders numbers are in order (1,2,3,..) you can count them and then maybe accept the pattern in a way suitable for use String.format("%s/%s-%s/%s.%s",m("placeholder1")...)